# Dumping a Text file into a VB.net program

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I have a VB.net program that I have reading a text file, what is the best way to put the text file into VB to be able to check if a string is on one of the lines in a text file, sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim fileText as string = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("c:\AnyFile.txt")
```

And to check whether a specific line is present in the string, use the `Contains` method :)

[Contains method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

Comment: For my usage, I think this will work, to search for the line, could i put filetest.Contains(vbnewline & "somestring" & vbnewline)?

Comment: Not sure why you'd use the `My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText()` method rather than `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()`.  Seems unnecessarily VB-lockin-ified.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to read the file as an array of strings rather then one lump string, if your doing alot of per line comparisions.

See the MSDN reference to the System.IO.File class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx

System.IO.File.ReadAllLines

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx

```
Dim fileLines() as string = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\AnyFile.txt")
```

Edit - woops, updated link

Comment: How would I search this? If it works better then the other one, I'll choose this answer.

Comment: for each line as string in fileLines
 if line="somestring" then
  messagbox.show("got one!")
 end if
end for

Comment: what exactly are you trying to find out of the text? if it's something simple a bit of linq will do the trick maybe, like:

dim foundStrings = from line in fileLines where line = "somestring" select line

for each matchString in foundStrings
 'at this point everything in the loop is guanteed to be a match
 do_something_thing_usefull(matchString)
end

Comment: Erm, i just want a function that returns true/false if it's in there.